# Value webSettings not found error in a Scalatra project

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra

I have a Scalatra project with the following `build.sbt`

```
organization := "com.example"

name := "scalatra-project"

version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

seq(webSettings :_*)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % "2.0.1",
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % "2.0.1",
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs" % "2.0.2",
  "org.scala-tools.testing" %% "specs" % "1.6.9",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "container",
  "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided",
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.4-SNAPSHOT",
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mongodb" % "2.4-M5",
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mongodb-record" % "2.4-M5"
)

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

resolvers += "Scala Tools Snapshots" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/"

resolvers += "Scala Tools Releases" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/"

resolvers += "Maven Repo" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
```

When I run `sbt`, I get the following error:

```
error: not found: value webSettings seq(webSettings :_*)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the plugin settings as mentioned here https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). I added plugins.sbt to project directory with the following contents `libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion(v => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % (v+"-0.2.10"))` and that fixed the problem.